# Change Order status on click in Woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, plugins, http-post

I creating a custom plugin to update woocommerce orders
so i proceed to display the Orders
and i created a button to change order status to *Completed* on click,
i created a `POST` form and used `wp_nonce_field()` function

and used this action to update the status

```
 add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'change_status' );
    function change_status(){

        // basic security check
        if ( ! isset( $_POST['_change_status'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['_change_status'], 'change_status' ) ) {
            return;
        }

        // make sure order id is submitted
        if ( ! isset( $_POST['order_id'] ) ){
            $order_id = intval( $_POST['order_id'] );
            $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
            $order->update_status('completed', '', true);
            return;
        }
    }
```

this my function to list orders
`$orders = wc_get_orders( array( 'numberposts' => -1 ) );`

and i did foreach to list all orders

and this my form

```
<?php foreach ($orders as $order){ ?>
        <tr id="" >
            <th scope="row" >
                <div>
                    <span  aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span></span>
                </div>
            </th>
            <td>#<?php echo $order->get_order_number(); echo ' ' . $order->get_billing_first_name(); echo ' ' . $order->get_billing_last_name(); ?> </td>
            <td><?php echo $order->get_id(); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $order->get_formatted_billing_address() ?></td>
            <td>

                <form method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="order_id" value="<?php echo esc_attr($order->get_id());?>">
                    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'change_status', '_change_status' ); ?>
                    <input type="submit" value="I Got It!">
                    <?php echo str_replace('-', ' ', $order->get_status()); ?>
                </form>


            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
```

**but nothing updated** , What is my issue ?

Comment: Actually your code is not really testable. Where exactly and how do you display the form (which hooked function). *"Your question should be updated to include … … **the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem**"*.

Comment: Thanks i will update the question now

Comment: it' clear enough?

Comment: @mohamednasser No, it is not. In the `<form>` you use `$order->get_id();` 
where did you add this code? which file? through which hook? how do you access the `$order` object?